# Increase default size of list for Spring boot properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm running a Spring boot application with the below configuration

```
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix= "app.sample")
    @Component
    public class PropGenerator{

        private List<String> list;

        public List<String> getList() {
            return list;
        }
        public void setList(List<String> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }
}
```

My `application.properties` has 300 entries configured in the format below

app.sample.list[0]=value1
.
.

app.sample.list[299]=value300

When I run the program, I get the below error

```
    Invalid list index in property path 'list[279]'; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 279, Size: 251
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 279, Size: 251
```

How can I manually override the size of the list so that all 300 values are auto populated in the `list` variable? I came across @InitBinder, but  could not get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

We do auto-grow collections when we have to and there used to be a limit that was changed in Spring Boot 1.3.7 (see [#6436](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6436)). Depending on the version you are currently using, an upgrade should fix it. If it doesn't, please create a sample that reproduces the problem and create an issue [in the Spring Boot issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues)

Answer (score 0):

You should not (ab)use property file as data store. Use database instead. You [can use `data.sql` script](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) to pre-populate database with your values.